# Stepy jQuery wizard form with Rails app. Issues installing / forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to integrate the Stepy jQuery plug-in (http://wbotelhos.com/stepy) with my rails form to create a wizard. I'd rather not use something like Wicked - something quick on the front-end is prefered.

I've added the javascript and CSS in their own files to my asset pipeline and installed `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`and put `//= require jquery.ui.all` in my asset pipeline as well.

Even after this, I can't seem to get this to work inside the rails app. Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong? I'm still learning the asset pipeline and javascript, so help is certainly appreciated.

All three steps are showing up in my form view instead of separate steps as follows:

[image: wizardsnap]

application.js

```
$('#steps').stepy();
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@wizard) do |f| %>

  <form id="steps">
    <fieldset title="Step 1">
      <legend>Step 1</legend> 
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :field1 %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :field1 %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset title="Step 2">
      <legend>Step 2</legend> 
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :field2 %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :field2 %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset title="Step 3">
      <legend>Step 3</legend> 
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :field3 %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :field3 %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </form>

<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

I ended up using the wizard which is part of this gem: `github.com/stephenbaldwin/fuelux-rails` which works so far. However, I'm still open to suggestions about how to get the above working.

Comment: Open the page with Chrome Inspector (or similar), and make sure in the sources tab that stepy is among the scripts loaded. If it is, put `$('#steps').stepy();` into the console and report back.

Comment: nickcoxdotme - it appears the scripts are loading. Adding $('#steps').stepy(); results in an empty []

Comment: I ended up using the wizard which is part of this gem. https://github.com/stephenbaldwin/fuelux-rails Works so far. Still can't figure out the issue with the above wizard. Hum.